# static content doesn't load in spring boot application

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-boot, mustache

I'm using spring boot and mustache. I try to load page with static css, but styles doesn't load with page. Previous time when I had same problem I just put all static content in a static directory, but now it doesn't help me. Previous time I used Spring Security, but now don't. Don't think that this has any connection.
Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="table">
        <form method="get" action="filter" class="table">
            <input type="text" name="caller" placeholder="Caller"/>
            <input type="text" name="destination" placeholder="Call recpient"/>
            <input type="date" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom">
            <input type="date" id="dateTo" name="dateTo">
            <input type="time" id="timeFrom" name="timeFrom">
            <input type="time" id="timeTo" name="timeTo">
            <button type="submit">Find</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        {{#listOfCalls}}
            <tr>
                <th>{{name}}</th>
                <th>{{caller}}</th>
                <th>{{destination}}</th>
                <th>{{date}}</th>
                <th>{{timeFrom}}</th>
                <th>{{timeTill}}</th>
                <th>{{lengthOfCall}}</th>
            </tr>
        {{/listOfCalls}}
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my resource folder hierarchy:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwOcu.png

Comment: Do you use `spring-boot-starter-mustache`?

Comment: Yes. 
`compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mustache', version: '2.2.4.RELEASE'`

Comment: Strange, cannot see any mistake. Here is a minimal working demo [basic spring-boot mustache setup](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/mustache).

Comment: Problem resolved, but in a strange way. 
I didn't have this:
`@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration {
}
`

Comment: Good, you got it working, but you should not need an extra `@Configuration`, or have you disabled on or more @AutoConfigurations?

Comment: If I correctly understand, you re talking about `@AutoConfigurations` annotation. I didn't have it all. Only one place where I have `@Configuration` is WebMvcConfiguration, which about I wrote higher.